# Jenkins pipeline - scp command getting permission denied with sshagent

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, scp

When using the `sshagent` wrapper, I'm able to `ssh` into server A and server B, but when using the `scp` command, I get permission denied

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'pipeline'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('SSH to remote host') {

            steps {
                sshagent(credentials: ['myCredentials']) {
                    sh '''
                        ssh userBar@server.a hostname -f
                        ssh userBar@server.a ls -l
                        
                        ssh userFoo@server.b hostname -f
                        ssh userFoo@server.b "echo 'hello world' >> thisFile.txt && ls -l"

                        scp userFoo@server.b:~/thisFile.txt  userBar@server.a:~/thisFile.txt 
                     
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running, the `ssh` commands return as expected, but the scp command chucks out the below

```
+ scp 'userFoo@server.b:~/thisFile.txt'  'userBar@server.a:~/thisFile.txt'
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the [scp docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html). Looks like scp tries to copy data b/w the remote hosts directly.

1. We need to pass the `-3` option.

> ```
>  -3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the
>          local host.  Without this option the data is copied
>          directly between the two remote hosts.  Note that, when
>          using the legacy SCP protocol (via the -O flag), this
>          option selects batch mode for the second host as scp cannot
>          ask for passwords or passphrases for both hosts.  This mode
>          is the default.
> ```

2. We can use the `-A` option to forward the agent on the remote

> ```
>  -A      Allows forwarding of ssh-agent(1) to the remote system.
>          The default is not to forward an authentication agent.
> ```

I have tried both of the above. Both seem to be working in my setup.

Comment: `-A` didn't work but `-3` did work! Thank you!